# addressComponents attribute on a GMSPlace object is not visible

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

the addressComponents property on a GMSPlace is private,not public, this is an bug or it's normal?

If is not a bug how do I take the property?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has been made public in the newer versions (I believe the change was introduced in version 1.12.2, if I remember correctly).